# JavaFX change cursor of all stages

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have an application that has a lot of stages, doing all sorts of different things. I was wondering if it is possible to change the Cursor of the entire application, rather than having to change it for all scenes.

For example, if the user does a long running task, I want the Cursor to change to the wait cursor for all scenes. When this task is finished, then I want the cursor to change back to the regular cursor.

I understand that to change the cursor for a particular scene you can do

```
scene.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
```

I would rather not have to iterate through all of the stages in my application, and change the cursor for each one.

I'm wondering if you can change the cursor at the Application level, rather than the scene level. I haven't found anything online that suggests you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no direct way to do this at an application level (that I know of). However, the cursor is a property, so you can bind all the scenes' cursors to a single value.

So something like:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

    private final ObjectProperty<Cursor> cursor = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(Cursor.DEFAULT);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Parent root =  ... ;
        // ...

        someButton.setOnAction(event -> {
            Parent stageRoot = ... ;
            Stage anotherStage = new Stage();
            anotherStage.setScene(createScene(stageRoot, ..., ...));
            anotherStage.show();
        });

        primaryStage.setScene(createScene(root, width, height));
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    private static Scene createScene(Parent root, double width, double height) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, width, height);
        scene.cursorProperty().bind(cursor);
        return scene ;
    }
}
```

Now any time you do

```
cursor.set(Cursor.WAIT);
```

any scene created via the `createScene(...)` method will change its cursor.

Obviously the cursor property and utility method don't have to be defined in the Application subclass; you can put these wherever is convenient for your application structure.